# Updating User session to reflect latest access level changes

Tags: session, joomla-user-groups, access

When there is any change in user object like usergroup etc during a session then these changes does not get reflected immediately in the current session.

User needs to logout and then again login to see the changes.

What if the current user session has been updated with the latest changes so that there will be no need to logout/re-login to check the changes.

Is there any major impact over the complete Joomla functionality which i should consider before doing such changes?

Comment: As @George has already mentioned, it's quite a tough task but I believe the [EU e-Privacy Directive](http://www.richeyweb.com/development/joomla-plugins/111-system-eu-e-privacy-directive) plugin has achieved this for authentication levels using a slight hacky method. Might be worth taking a look

Answer (score 3):

This is a very common problem in Joomla installs and to be honest there isn't a super simple fix. We've implemented a **limited** fix in 3.4 which allows you to clear the access rights cached for the currently logged in user (https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/user/user.php#L488). However it will not change the access rights of any other users on the site.

However any attempts we've made to fix the problems for all users has resulted in unacceptable performance impacts. To be honest whilst it's not ideal your best bet is probably to keep having the users log and back in again.